# Oral vs Poster vs Workshop. Which is the most prestigious in the context of Computer Vision and Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: conference, computer-science, presentation, poster, workshop

This question is mainly about the perceived prestige of various events at conferences. Is there a hierarchy to it? Asking this in the perspective of being the presenter. Another way of putting it would be is "10 oral papers on my resume better" or "3 oral, 3 posters, 3 workshops, 1 tutorial on my resume better".

1. Oral
2. Posters
3. Workshops
4. Tutorials
5. etc.

A detailed post regarding which is the most prestigious and why would be appreciated.

Example conferences:

1. [Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)](http://cvpr2017.thecvf.com/)
2. [International Conference on Learning Representations (ICLR)](http://www.iclr.cc/)
3. [Association of the Advancement of Artificial Intelligence (AAAI)](http://www.aaai.org)
4. [International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML)](http://www.icml.cc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**0. Invited/plenary talk at the main conference**

**1. Paper in the main proceedings with an oral presentation**

**2. Paper in the main proceedings with a poster presentation**

**3. Everything else**

---

Having a paper in the primary conference proceedings is more prestigious than not having a paper in the primary conference proceedings.  If I understand how CVPR, ICML, and the like work, that means (oral presentations and posters) are more prestigious than (workshop, tutorial, or other).

Only a small number of CVPR/ICML/etc papers are accepted for oral presentation, so having a paper with an oral presentation is more prestigious than having a paper with a poster presentation.

Workshops and tutorials are apples and oranges.  A workshop presentation is more likely to be associated with your own original research (if only in preliminary form).  On the other hand, a tutorial presentation is a significant community service, and being invited to give a tutorial is a mark of community standing.  I would rank tutorials slightly ahead of workshop papers, but I'm sure not everyone would agree with me.

Comment: Actually, as of 2022 all accepted main track papers in ICML are oral. Some are "spotlight", which is like a short-oral in other conferences.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to give you a partial answer, waiting for a more complete explanation of your question. The highest prestige is in giving an opening or closing speech at a plenary session in a big conference. Then the same kind of talk at a secondary conference. Then a oral presentation at a parallel session in big confernence in your field, followed by oral/parallel/small. Poster in my opinion comes after all of this. Not sure what you mean by workshop, and tutorial. If you are the one leading the workshop, giving the tutorial, it's a big thing. If you are just attending, then it counts as training yourself, not educating others.